# Cannot pass thingspeak json to android

Tags: android, json

I took sensor reading of bmp180 and passed to thingspeak and the graph was displayed.Now I want to get the json of thingspeak to my android phone.But the json in the thingspeak data is not getting in my phone.Any help would be appreciated.Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String PATIENTS_LIST_URL = "http://thingspeak.com/channels/201342/field/1.json";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> patientList;

 Button button;
    TextView textview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textview=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_get_string);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                GetJsonData();
            }
        });

    }

private void GetJsonData() {
    final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            PATIENTS_LIST_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
         //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           textview.setText(response.toString());

            try {

                JSONArray  data = response.getJSONArray("feeds");

            JSONObject eachData = data.getJSONObject(0);
            String  address=eachData.getString("field2");

             //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                     //   "field1::"+address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    // Snack(error.getMessage());
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String>map = new HashMap<String,String>();
            return map;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);
}
}
```

Comment: Add your response to the question.

Answer (score 2):

`field2` doesn't exist in the feeds part of the Json response.

Try changing

`String address = eachData.getString("field2");`

to

`String address = eachData.getString("field1");`

Truncated response from your URL for reference:

```
{
   "channel":{
      "id":201342,
      "name":"Weather Monitoring Station",
      "description":"The channel provides live weather information of the city such as temperature and atmospheric pressure.",
      "latitude":"0.0",
      "longitude":"0.0",
      "field1":"Temperature",
      "field2":"Pressure",
      "created_at":"2016-12-09T08:32:45Z",
      "updated_at":"2017-02-10T15:46:27Z",
      "last_entry_id":371
   },
   "feeds":[
      {
         "created_at":"2017-01-26T07:33:03Z",
         "entry_id":272,
         "field1":"29.57"
      },
      {
         "created_at":"2017-01-26T07:33:25Z",
         "entry_id":273,
         "field1":"29.61"
      }
      ....
   ]
}
```